# Which wil be used between the colon and semi-colon in the below sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

1. People are more horrified from the animal; tiger.
2. People are more horrified from the animal: tiger.

Comment: “afraid from” sounds strange, and we need to know what “ABC” is to know the correct punctuation.

Comment: I have corrected

Comment: still odd!  "afraid of" or "horrified of".  But the structure of the whole sentence is odd  "People are more afraid of tigers.   (presumably in comparison to something else given by the context.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you view this as a punctuation issue.

**Punctuation is not grammar; it is established by Style Guides and does not even exist in the spoken language.**

Although there are many commonalities among Style Guides that you should know if you want your writings to be considered acceptable by most publishers, punctuation is a tertiary issue behind basic grammar and idiomatic locutions.

In your sentences, punctuation disappears as an issue if we address the idiomatic flaws in your example. To be frank, I am not 100% sure that I even know what you intend to say, but I suspect it is:

> People are more terrified by tigers than by any other animal.

If that is what you mean, then you have no issue with colons or semi-colons.